# Hide div on mouseout of one of two divs, but not in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mouseover, mouseout

I currently have two `<div>`s. When hovering the first, the second should fade in. When `mouseout`ing the first or the second, the second should fade out again. However, when moving the mouse from the first to the second, the second should stay (like a mouseover-menu).

What I've implemented now are simple `mouseover`/`mouseout` event handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/tC3ZL/2/.

```
$('#div1').mouseover(function() {
    $('#div2').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#div1').mouseout(function() {
    $('#div2').fadeOut(500);
});

$('#div2').hide().mouseout(function() {
    $('#div2').fadeOut(500);
});
```

The problem is that the requirement of showing the second div persistently when moving the mouse from the first to the second div is not working - when moving the mouse from the first to the second div will raise the `mouseout` of the first div.

How could I possibly add this rule in my code? I tried just doing http://jsfiddle.net/tC3ZL/1/:

```
$('#div2').mouseover(function() {
    $('#div2').fadeIn(500);
});
```

but this makes the second div fade out **and** fade in when moving the mouse from the first to the second div, whilst it should just stay without any effects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code instead of yours

```
    $('#div1').mouseover(function() {
        $('#div2').stop();
        $('#div2').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('#div2').hide().mouseout(function() {
        $('#div2').fadeOut(500);
    });
```